# What is the correct mysql query which searches for fields containing forward slashes?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have to write a query which checks for a field  "zone" and its value in one of the rows is "inter/intra". I need to query this field to retrieve its value. Something like

```
select id from table where zone = 'inter/intra'
```

OR

```
select id from table where zone like 'inter/intra'
```

However this query is failing everytime.

Please tell me the right query for this.

Comment: You meant you are getting error or not returning the result that you are expecting? If you are getting error message, what's that?

Comment: Both queries do the same thing. `LIKE` works like `=` unless you have wildcard characters (`%` or `_`). Strings can be escaped by backslashes (`\\`) but not by the forward slashes you have here. Also: what do you mean by **failing everytime** *(sic)*? Syntax error? Wrong results? Computer catches fire?

Comment: are you sure you don't have spaces, or other characters in your field zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use like, you need to add wildcards: the % symbol represents any arbitrary string. For example this will find the id of the record where zone contains "inter/intra":

```
select id from table where zone like '%inter/intra%'
```

This will find the id of the record where zone starts with "inter/intra":

```
select id from table where zone like 'inter/intra%'
```

This will find the id of the record where zone ends with "inter/intra":

```
select id from table where zone like '%inter/intra'
```